# python , linking a texture in Blender with a name composed by fixed part + random number

Tags: python, file, path, textures, blender

a very noob question I can't find an answer. I need to load some image files via script, and everything is working but now the client has changed the naming system and he added a serial name in the middle of the name. the name ,instead of being "texture name" + "_folder_name".png (example cube_A34DF.png) , now it is like this  "texture name" + "random number" + "_folder_name".png . that random number in the middle messes up all my work . how do I refer to is in a generic way? in the script, when I can the file path , what should I put instead of the random number so Blender read the file name ignoring the randpart of the name that changes? it's not working with "texture_name*" . I tried googling but no luck. thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you reliably determine whether numbers in the file name belong to the texture name or the random number? That would be necessary to extract the texture name.

Comment: @JakobF it's a completely random number assigned by an external logic and since I need to batch process thousands of folders with textures, I can't rename all of them

Comment: You can't use `*` in functions like `open()`, `os.listdir()`, etc. But you can use `*` in `glob.glob()` to read all filenames -ie. `glob.glob("cube_*.png")`. You could write script to rename filenames or you could keep them as dictionary `names = {"normal_name": "name_with_random_number", ...}` and later use `names["normal_name"]` to get `"name_with_random_number"`

Comment: somebody gave me this , to delete the files that start with the desired name "import bpy
import os
import glob

path = os.getcwd()
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith('yes'):
        os.remove(join(path,file))" now, how can I use the same principle for assigning a particular image to a texture?